# Writing to CSV file. TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable

Tags: python, file, csv, typeerror

Am trying to write a currency conveter, which has code and a csv file, where the csv file can be edited to save new exchange rates between uses. But i have a problem writing to the file and changing the rate:

```
 def change():
    print()
    print()
    print()
    print("1) Change existing exchange rate.")
    print("2) Add new exchange rates.")
    print("3) Quit.")
    exRtFile = open ('exchangeRate.csv')
    exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
    exchWriter = csv.writer(exRtFile)
    loop2=0
    while loop2==0:
        selected=int(input("Please select an option: "))
        if selected == 1:
            change = input("What rate would you like to change: ")
            changeRt = float(input("What would you like to change the rate to: "))
            for row in exchReader:
                currency = row[0]
                if currency == change:
                    crntRt = row[1]
                    crntRt = changeRt
                    exchWriter.writerows(crntRt)
```

Heres and example of input/output:

```
1) Change existing exchange rate.
2) Add new exchange rates.
3) Quit.
Please select an option: 1
What rate would you like to change: Euro
What would you like to change the rate to: 1.23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    converter()
  File "py", line 21, in converter
    change()
  File "py", line 91, in change
    exchWriter.writerows(crntRt)
TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable
```

Comment: Without knowing the input, it's hard to debug this. Could you provide a working example? But the error is pretty self-eplanatory: Either use ```writerow``` (notice the singular; you only want to write a single row within the loop, right?) or pass an iterable to the ```writerows```-method.

Answer (score 0):

`writeRows()`, by its nature, is expecting a variable holding a bunch of values, each value containing the data to be be written to one row in the output file.

Because you are giving `writerows()` a single `float` value, it's responding by telling you it doesn't know how to turn that into multiple rows -- in "Python speak" `must be iterable` means "I can't figure how to get multiple values from the item you gave me".

You probably have a number of other issues in your code.  In particular:

```
 crntRt = row[1]
 crntRt = changeRt
 exchWriter.writerows(crntRt)
```

makes me think that you're somehow expecting to see the value of `row[1]` in your output, but you won't because the next line overwrites that value with the new exchange rate.

Comment: i am trying to get the location of the value (crntRt = row[1]), then change it to the new value (crntRt = changeRt), then write that to the file (exchWriter.writerows(crntRt)). What would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: This is not an entirely clear statement of the problem.  You should be aware that you can't read and write the same CSV file at the same time -- the csv module does not perform "in place" updates.  You must rewrite the *entire* file.  So your basic structure will be 1) Read the entire file into memory storing it in a dictionary or similar, 2) collect updates from the user, applying each one to the in-memory structure, and 3) when user is finished and wants to save changes, overwrite the disk file with the entire in-memory structure as CSV.

Comment: Is there an example of this somewhere?